# Problem displaying result in Sieve of Eratosthenes code in C

Tags: c, malloc, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm writing a code for the "Sieve of Eratosthenes" in C, which prints all the prime numbers up to n. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "input2.h"

int main() 
{
    int n = read_int();
    int length = n-1;

    int *block_of_memory = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));


    for(int i = 2; i <= length; i++)
    {
        block_of_memory[i] = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i*i <= length; i++)
    {
        if(block_of_memory[i] == 1)
        {
            for(int j = i*i; j < length; j = j+i)
            {
                block_of_memory[j] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= length; ++i)
    {
        if(block_of_memory[i] == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }

    }



    print_prime(block_of_memory, length);

    free(block_of_memory);

    return 0;

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. When I want all the prime uptown 5 (for example), I get:

```
Give a number: 5
1
1
4, 5,
```

Comment: Allocing for a single int, accessing as an array. Fishy.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Ideally use hard-coded sample data for demonstration, instead of more complicated code for input.

Comment: Note `i*i` can overflow in  `for(int i = 2; i*i <= length; i++)` when `length` is near `INT_MAX`.   `for(int i = 2; i <= length/i; i++)` does not.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allocating enough memory:

```c
int *block_of_memory = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

should actually be:

```c
int *block_of_memory = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

This way, you allocate space for the entire array of `n` ints, and not just one int. Also, [never cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5923139). In addition, your code has some logic errors:

```c
for(int j = i*i; j < length; j = j+i)
{
    block_of_memory[j] = 0;
}
```

should actually be:

```c
for(int j = i*i; j <= length; j = j+i)
{
    block_of_memory[j] = 0;
}
```

(notice the `< length` becomes `<= length`). This way, every element gets checked properly, including the element at `length - 1`.

Comment: I totally agree. Only luck would mean that this fixe the non-prime output though.

Comment: @Yunnosch Oops! It turns out there was an edge case (when n - 1 is composite) that the code breaks on, and I didn't find it when testing my solution. Upon looking further, I found a bug and edited it into my answer.

Comment: You show a solution and point out the differences. If you explain why they are necessary you can have my upvote.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but it literally gave me the same output as before,

Comment: Really? Because I get the correct output with [this](https://pastebin.com/EasW4xwi) code.

Comment: Rather than code a type in, use `block_of_memory = malloc(sizeof *block_of_memory * n);` to avoid mistakes.  Also easier to review and maintain.